# How to use OData filter in dynamic array

Tags: arrays, filter, nested, odata

I am trying to filter nested array using ?$filter in odata filter
but it is not working properly
parent array got filtered but not child one.

### My Array

{

```
"value": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Country": "India",
        "language": [
            {
                "Lid": 1,
                "State": "telengana",

                "Statuelanguage": "Telgu",

                "Place to visit": [

                       "p3","p4"


                ]
            },
            {
                "Lid": 2,
                "State": "Delhi",

                "Statuelanguage": "Hindi",

                "Place to visit": [

                       "p5","p6"


                ]
            },
             {
                "Lid": 3,
                "State": "UP",

                "Statuelanguage": "Hindi",

                "Place to visit": [

                       "p7","p8"


                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

### Expected Responce

{

```
"value": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Country": "India",
        "language": [
            {
                "Lid": 1,
                "State": "telengana",

                "Statuelanguage": "Telgu",

                "Place to visit": [

                       "p3","p4"


                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

### Filter query

### ?$filter=language/any(c: c/Lid eq 1)

but when i am trying to use the filter, it is filtering the parent one not the child
it returns all 3 child to me

Answer (score 2):

So it works as expected :)

`$filter` parameter is used to filter collection that you're querying.

To filter expanded/related collection (language in your case) you have to use expand filter feature:

```
...$expand=language($filter=Lid eq 1)
```

BUT: It is only possible in OData v4.

[ref for webapi](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/04-03-filter-in-expand/)

[nested filter description](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#nestedFilter)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was looking for an answer which will help filter an Array of Primitive values, For example

```
otherMails: [
   "mytestmail@goole.com",
   "mytestmail@yahoo.com"
]
```

So to have a Odata query such that it filters resources for us should be as follows , this I have implemented on Azure Graph API and got the result

```
$filter=otherMails/any(s:startsWith(s,'mytestmail@goole.com'))
```

I have went through this documentation of OData for same [here](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/)https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/